# Dynamic HTML table creation with multiple rows and columns in Power shell

Tags: html, json, powershell, foreach, html-table

With reference to  sample JSON, I am trying to create dynamic HTML table but how ever i am failing to get  specific column name with specific row data .

**Conditions:**

- As per JSON Sample, I have "Table_0" & "Table_1" table name , only for first table data i need to convert to HTML. No more another tables. That is reason in my script I am accessing only

  ```
  $dataTable = ($response | ConvertFrom-Json).Tables[0]
  ```
- In my Sample JSON, i have only 2 columns but in reality i may have single or many more columns with respective data in Rows
- Column names are not fixed. In another response of JSON, I may have different columns (single column or multiple columns) but data with respective columns will be available.
  say Ex: Another JSON , I have 4 columns, so my output should show 4 columns with that number of rows  in HTML table.
- JSON File Format is fixed, only Columns and Rows will be added/removed for every response.

**Script:**

```
 $response = get-content <JSONFilePath>
 $dataTable = ($response | ConvertFrom-Json).Tables[0]
 $columncount = $dataTable.Columns.count
  $header = "<table border=1><tr>"
  for($i=0;$i -lt $columncount;$i++){
    $header = $header+"<th>"+$dataTable.Columns[$i].ColumnName+"</th>"
  }
  $header = $header +"</tr>"
      $Lines ="<tr>"
       for($i=0;$i -lt $columncount;$i++)
     {   
      $val=""
     foreach($rowdata in $dataTable.Rows)
     {
        ###Unable to get Specific row data for specific Column name
        $val = $val+"<td>"+$i[$rowdata]+"</td>"
      }
      $Lines = $Lines+ $val +"</tr>"
     }

       $tableval = $header+ $Lines +"</table>"
      Write-Output $tableval
```

**JSON:**

```
     {
 "Tables": [
{
  "TableName": "Table_0",
  "Columns": [
    {
      "ColumnName": "Name",
      "DataType": "String",
      "ColumnType": "string"
    },
    {
      "ColumnName": "Rating",
      "DataType": "Double",
      "ColumnType": "real"
    }
  ],
  "Rows": [
    [
      "Satya",
      1000.0
    ],
    [
      "Pavan",
      2000.00
    ]
  ]
},
{
  "TableName": "Table_1",
  "Columns": [
    {
      "ColumnName": "Value",
      "DataType": "String",
      "ColumnType": "string"
    }
  ],
  "Rows": [
    [
    ]
         ]
         }
   ]
   }
```

**Output:**

```
              <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
   <th>Rating</th> 
   </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Satya</td>
     <td>1000</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Pavan</td>
     <td>2000</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: I think you meant `$rowdata[$i]` instead of `$i[$rowdata]`. But you should put the column incrementer `$i` in the inner loop instead of the outer loop.

Comment: @Rich Moss Can you suggest provide script of that change. Still unable to get correct output.